# What sans-serif font is use for this text ("POWERED BY EMAIL")?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

[image: font for email and powered by]

What is the font type in this image? It was created by a co-worker that is no longer at my company.

Comment: Have you tried using an on-line service like http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ to identify it?

Comment: It's close to Franklin Gothic, though not quite.

Comment: @DA01 ironically, the question asked using the same font as in the question itself :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm almost positive that it's [Open Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans). The "O" is less geometric than Proxima Nova, and the "Y" is exactly like the picture.

[image]

Comment: I think we have a winner!

Comment: (Also, how embarrassing is that to all of us?...the font was the very font this site is using! :) )

Answer (score 2):

Probably it is [Proxima Nova font](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/marksimonson/proxima-nova/)

[image]

or [Motiva Sans Thin](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/niramekko/motiva-sans/):

[image]

[Alright Sans](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/okay-type/alright-sans/) is close too but M does not match:

[image]

Comment: That's pretty close!

Comment: That "W" looks very similar if it's not the same font

Comment: There are some very slight differences in the metrics...the O for example. The original is a bit 'squooshed' on the top and sides, while this is a bit of a smoother curve. The angle of the Y is slightly different. But it's definitely extremely close. I'd go to MyFonts and look through all of the related fonts.

Comment: @DA01 I agree. Probably, topic starter will find it sufficient..